# In ASP.Net MVC, how can you manage dependencies between views and layout pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We're working with ASP.Net MVC and Google Publisher Tags (GPT).

GPT requires that you create javascript "slots" in the `<head>` and some html+script that goes into the `<body>`. The key dependency here is that in both places is an id that must match. So the head will contain some Javascript that includes something like:

```
<head>
<script>
...
DefineSlot('div-gpt-ad-123456789-0', 'foo', 'bar')
...
</script></head>
```

and

```
<body>
...
<div id='div-gpt-ad-123456789-0'>
  <script> 
  ...
  Display('div-gpt-ad-123456789-0')
  ...
  </script>
</div>
...
```

How can we manage the dependencies between these 2 pieces code? **The critical piece is that the id of both parts must match.**

We want to use MVC to create these pieces of code dynamically. So in any view, partial or layout, I will be able to add a helper call that might look like:

```
@Html.CreateAd(size, "foo", "bar")
```

`@Html.CreateAd` can be called anywhere in a view, partial view, layout, or nested layout.

How do you use ASP.Net MVC to program the code that goes into `<head>`?

Any suggestions are appreciated. I'm just looking for direction, not a full blown solution.

Many Thanks.

Comment: you could use a section eg. @RenderSection("Head") and populate that in whatever views use the layout page and use some kind of application setting for the actual number

Comment: The information necessary to create the code in the header comes from more than one place. It comes from a _HeaderLayout, a _SideLayout, a _FooterLayout and, in some cases, the view. How do you gather all these pieces together to put into a single code block?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, you need a bit more example to show exactly how this code is generated

Comment: _LayoutSide.cshtml might have Html.CreateAd("position","side") , _LayoutFooter.cshtml might have Html.CreateAd("position","bottom"). In the header, I need to generate 2 DefineSlot() lines in the script element. In the body, there would be 2 divs that each wrap a <script>DisplayAd(

Comment: I think Chad is on the right track below. The problem is that I'm trying to create/use some type of makeshift page ad registry and that the Html.CreateAd will populate the registry and then Html.CreateAdHeader will read all the items that have been added to the registry. But views, layouts and such are script code and not designed for this type of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few different ways to do this.

You can add the id's to the ViewData or a base viewmodel.

Then OnActionExecuting or OnActionExecuted in a base controller or via actionfilters, you can add your data to whichever place you prefer to. If you need examples for this, please leave a comment on this answer.

Then, your helpers (one for each section) you can read from one of the 2 sources you decided on. I have gone both routes.  If all of your pages are going to have an ad, then I would lean towards the base ViewModel. If it's more of a rare occurrence ViewData would be more appropriate.

To access the viewdata within an htmlHelper Extension method:

```
public static class HtmlExtension
{
    public static MvcHtmlString RenderAdHead(this HtmlHelper h)
    {
        h.ViewContext.ViewData.Model // a test and cast here
        h.ViewContext.ViewData["AdIdentifier"] // test for null and cast here

        string tags = String.Empty;
        //build up string to resemble your script/html tags using either of the 
        //sources above, so long as either source is not empty.

        return new HtmlMvcString(tags);
    }
}
```

And some code for a filter:

```
public class AdvertisingFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
       List<String> idList = null; // list of string might not be adequate. depends on your implementation
        //read advertising ids from your datastore or wherever you have. 



        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["advertisingFilter"] = idList;
    }
}
```

The basecontroller is pretty much the same, instead you have the controllercontext directly. You just have to be sure all your controllers inherit from them.

Comment: Is this dependent upon the layout of the code across the view and teh layouts? Suppose, for example, that I put the Html.RenderAhead call in the head of a _LayoutPage. Now, I happen to want an ad to appear at the bottom of all pages, so I include an Html.CreateAd at the bottom of the body section. If script pages render in order, won't the Html.RenderAhead method return before it is fully populated?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that I understood the first part when I first read it. I believe that you are saying rather than putting Html.Ad in the layout pages and views that code should go into a base controller (for a default). The helpers then are placed into the views/layouts where needed and will pull from the ViewData/ViewBag/Model. IF I need to customize individual views, I can use an actionfilter on the Controller Action.

Comment: Sortof, yes. You will have 2 helpers. One that renders your head tag(s) and a second helper that you can place wherever in your view/layout etc. You didn't say you had more than one ad on a given page, so I didn't account for that. It's fairly trivial to do if you need that as well.

Comment: Makes sense. The thing that was throwing me was that it's just so common to throw a 3rd party Javascript widget inline without much thought. I was trying to apply that same thinking here, but you're right, creating the scripts that will go on many pages belongs in a base controller and the views are responsible for displaying the items.

Comment: Do you have any good examples showing how the Base Controller and action filters work?

Comment: It's one or the other. Don't do both.  let me dig up some code for you

Comment: I was thinking that I would use our ControllerBase to render the 5 ads that occur on 95% of pages. For those exceptions, I would use a FilterAttribute to override.

Comment: BaseController would be the same. the syntax is almost identical